# New design colour scheme

Tags: support, design

Maybe it's just me as my eyes isn't that good (but no need for glasses yet) but I find it the text/background contrast isn't enough as in I think the text colour is a bit light. Specially the vote/answer/view columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coincidentally, I work in website accessibility - though I'm a product developer not an accessibility expert.  The color contrast here (between #777 and #fff) is 4.48:1

This would not meet recommendations when measured against the most common accessibility standard, but only just. WCAG AA suggests a minimum contrast ratio of 4.5:1 for small text.  I used the WebAIM checker (http://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/).

If SE could just bump that grey to be a little bit darker it would definitely benefit some of our users.

Comment: Do you speak about the vote/answer/view column specifically or something more general?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson. The color contrast ratio of 1.48 specifically refers to the grey used in the vote/answer/view text.  Similar color contrast issues relate to the green used for accepted answers in the same columns - but I've not checked those.  Its best practice (and nice for their users with eyesight issues) but I believe there is no specific requirement for SE to meet these standards.

Comment: That said - its super easy to fix, and we have at least one user already saying its a problem for them.

Comment: I assume it's just a css update and nothing more, thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is a little light on contrast. We'll fix it shortly!

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the effort